# MysqlDump npm shows javascript heap out of memory.Works well for Mysql files less than 1 gb.anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

```
      mysqlDump({
          host: hostname,
          port: portname,
          user: username,
          password: password,
          database: datbasename,
          dest: /directory,
        }, function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    });
```

**This is my code and this works for smaller mysql files.**

```
    {
      "name": "projectname",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
        "compressing": "^1.2.3",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
        "current-date": "^0.1.1",
        "debug": "~2.6.9",
        "express": "~4.15.5",
        "file-encryptor": "^0.1.1",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
        "hbs": "~4.0.1",
        "monitor-dashboard": "^0.6.7",
        "morgan": "~1.9.0",
        "mysqldump": "^1.4.2",
        "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
        "pm2": "^2.10.2",
        "promise": "^8.0.1",
        "reload": "^2.2.2",
        "request": "^2.85.0",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
      },
      "config": {
        "days_interval": 7,
        "max_size": 5242880
      }
    }
```

**Thie above given is my package.json file so if there is any version problem.**

this is the error that pops up. <--- Last few GCs --->

```
> [5121:0x3e52ce0]   160788 ms: Mark-sweep 1468.6 (1526.4) -> 1468.4
> (1526.9) MB, 1413.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space
> requested [5121:0x3e52ce0]   162286 ms: Mark-sweep 1468.4 (1526.9) ->
> 1468.3 (1495.4) MB, 1497.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested [5121:0x3e52ce0]   163725 ms: Mark-sweep 1468.3 (1495.4) ->
> 1468.3 (1495.4) MB, 1439.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
```

========== JS stack trace =========================================

```
> Security context: 0x3f1c76625529 <JSObject>
>     1: /* anonymous */ [/home/rajesh/vishnu works/dump2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:~231]
> [pc=0x37a5a37e1095](this=0x35b8ca03d6a1 <Protocol map =
> 0x366e60ff7e71>)
>     2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0
>     3: write [/home/rajesh/vishnu works/dump2/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:~27]
> [pc=0x37a5a37f62c7](this=0x35b8ca03d5e1 <Parser map =
> 0x366e60fecc61>,chunk=0x39cd489b725...
> 
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory  1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]  2: 0x8cea7c
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*,
> bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]  4:
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  5:
> v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int)
> [/usr/local/bin/node]  6: 0xd88283 [/usr/local/bin/node]  7:
> v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**,
> v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]  8: 0x37a5a36042fd}}
```

1. **Now i can work with small files but large files shows this error .
       when i increase the RAM to higher value this error goes 
       and and similar error telling limit exceeded for maximum 
       lines comes up.can anyone help me out.I am really stuck with this .**

Answer (score 3):

The `mysqldump` NPM module is fatally flawed, and will never work with large databases. [It constructs the database dump completely in memory, as a string, before writing any data to a file](https://github.com/webcaetano/mysqldump/blob/9b965f26a3b2bad699d62420f7ae4cc70a71de5f/index.js#L91). If this is larger than memory, it will inevitably crash. Fixing this would require a major rewrite of the module, as it makes a pretty fundamental assumption that the dump can be stored in memory.

(It also assumes that it should dump all tables in parallel, and that it should do so by running a single `SELECT * FROM table` query for each table. Neither of these assumptions is true.)

Don't use this module. If you need to back up your database, use the `mysqldump` command-line tool, or other backup tools like [mydumper](https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper) or [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup). These tools are all designed to work with huge databases, and do not suffer from the limitations of the `mysqldump` NPM module.